# How to sort running applications on DDMS

Tags: android, ddms

I want to sort the running application list on DDMS, because every time that I need to debug the app that I'm developing, I spend a lot of time searching in the applications list for my app packagename.

[image: DDMS in eclipse]

Can someone help me please?